Can you scale NextJS instances in Wordpress Atlas?
I have a NextJS in Wordpress Atlas and I've been having an issue where page refreshes sometimes return 500 and sometimes not.
I was doing tests for an internal cache (inside NextJS internal) of the backend response, and so I loaded the page and then turned off access for the Backend.
I left it running like that for a couple of hours but then page refresh would show 500 some times (the error I configured to show when no cache data is available and backend is down).
This makes me wonder if this was a "different instances" having different cache object, since it is tied to the server instance.
But I could not find any information in the web about scaling the NextJS instances in Wordpress Atlas
